# Для чего нужно использовать объект класса BooleanVar вместо обычной переменной типа bool?

Tags: python, tkinter

Например , я написал очень простую программу на Tkinter . Есть 3 флажка , активируя которые , можно изменять текстовую область . Она отображает , какие флажки нажаты :

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame) :
    """Простое приложение"""
    def __init__(self,master) :
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    
    def create_widgets(self) :
        """Создаёт элементы управления"""
        self.is_first_checkbox = None # вопрос в этой строчке
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "Флажок 1",
                    variable = self.is_first_checkbox,
                    command = self.update_text
                    ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        
        self.is_second_checkbox = None # вопрос в этой строчке
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "Флажок 2",
                    variable = self.is_second_checkbox,
                    command = self.update_text
                    ).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        
        self.is_third_checkbox = None # вопрос в этой строчке
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "Флажок 3",
                    variable = self.is_third_checkbox,
                    command = self.update_text
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
        
        self.results_txt = Text(self,width = 40, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.results_txt.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
    
    def update_text(self) :
        """Обновляет текстовый элемент"""
        result = ""
        if self.is_first_checkbox :
            result += "Первый флажок активирован.\n"
        if self.is_second_checkbox :
            result += "Второй флажок активирован.\n"
        if self.is_third_checkbox :
            result += "Третий флажок активирован.\n"
        
        self.results_txt.delete(0.0,END)
        self.results_txt.insert(0.0,result)

window = Tk()
window.title("Флажки")
app = Application(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Результат - флажки активируются , но никаких изменений в текстовой области не происходит . Теперь я переписываю эту программу , заменяя обычные переменные на объекты класса `tkinter.BooleanVar` :

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame) :
    """Простое приложение"""
    def __init__(self,master) :
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    
    def create_widgets(self) :
        """Создаёт элементы управления"""
        self.is_first_checkbox = BooleanVar() # вопрос в этой строчке
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "Флажок 1",
                    variable = self.is_first_checkbox,
                    command = self.update_text
                    ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        
        self.is_second_checkbox = BooleanVar() # вопрос в этой строчке
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "Флажок 2",
                    variable = self.is_second_checkbox,
                    command = self.update_text
                    ).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        
        self.is_third_checkbox = BooleanVar() # вопрос в этой строчке
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text = "Флажок 3",
                    variable = self.is_third_checkbox,
                    command = self.update_text
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
        
        self.results_txt = Text(self,width = 40, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.results_txt.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
    
    def update_text(self) :
        """Обновляет текстовый элемент"""
        result = ""
        if self.is_first_checkbox.get() :
            result += "Первый флажок активирован.\n"
        if self.is_second_checkbox.get() :
            result += "Второй флажок активирован.\n"
        if self.is_third_checkbox.get() :
            result += "Третий флажок активирован.\n"
        
        self.results_txt.delete(0.0,END)
        self.results_txt.insert(0.0,result)

window = Tk()
window.title("Флажки")
app = Application(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Теперь всё работает корректно . Мой вопрос состоит в следующем : какой смысл в использовании этих объектов вместо обычных переменных , чем они отличаются от переменных , слылающихся на простые логические значения ? Почему переменные в этом случае не работают и не принимают значение автоматически ? И тогда , в каких вообще случаях нужны использовать объекты класса BooleanVar .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tkinter.BooleanVar` -- это объект Tk и он умеет хранить и отдавать значение, а, например, в `self.is_first_checkbox` у вас был бы `False` или `True` и немного другое -- они не изменяемые, у них нет какого-либо метода для изменения их состояния (типа метода `set`).

Т.е. виджет `Checkbutton` умеет менять значение объекта переданного в `variable`, но для этого нужны изменяемые объекты с определенными атрибутами (`set` и `get`).

А чтобы проверка с `if self.is_first_checkbox :` имела смысл, виджету нужно менять значение самого атрибута объекта, т.е. что-то вроде `setattr(self, 'is_first_checkbox', True)`, а такое он не сможет сделать.

---

Немного подробнее про объект `BooleanVar` из tk:

```
class BooleanVar(Variable):
    """Value holder for boolean variables."""
    _default = False
    def __init__(self, master=None, value=None, name=None):
        """Construct a boolean variable.

        MASTER can be given as master widget.
        VALUE is an optional value (defaults to False)
        NAME is an optional Tcl name (defaults to PY_VARnum).

        If NAME matches an existing variable and VALUE is omitted
        then the existing value is retained.
        """
        Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)

    def set(self, value):
        """Set the variable to VALUE."""
        return self._tk.globalsetvar(self._name, self._tk.getboolean(value))
    initialize = set

    def get(self):
        """Return the value of the variable as a bool."""
        try:
            return self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
        except TclError:
            raise ValueError("invalid literal for getboolean()")
```

Как видно, у самого объекта есть методы для установки и получения значения через методы `set` и `get`. А "подкапотом" этих методов происходит работа с `tk`, что наталкивает на вывод, что простые типы python не могут заменить объекты `tk` для работы с `tk` :)